# I can not collect data from my json - React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have created a menu, with a submenu and a third child. So far I had it done simply with a `json` in local const data that is now commented. I need that from now on the data is collected from my json but I do not know how to do it. As it is now I get the following error: `'data' is not defined` ( in my render)

```
class Nav extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          navigation:[]
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
    fetch('json_menuFIN.php')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>{
        this.setState({navigation: data });
        console.log( data)
    })
}
    render(){
        const { data = null } = this.state.navigation;
        if ( this.state.navigation && !this.state.navigation.length ) { // or wherever your data may be
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <Menu data={this.state.navigation}/>
        )        
    }

}

const renderMenu = items => {
    return <ul>
      { items.map(i => {
        return <li>
          <a href={i.link}>{ i.title }</a>
          { i.menu && renderMenu(i.menu) }
        </li>
      })}
    </ul>
}

const Menu = ({ data }) => {
    return <nav>
      <h2>{ data.title }</h2>
      { renderMenu(data.menu) }
    </nav>
}
```

I do not know what else to do to make it work with what I have. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: in your render function change  `<Menu data={data}/>` to `<Menu data={this.state.navigation}/>`

Comment: @Andrii Golubenko If I change it, the following error occurs: Can not read property 'map' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `navigation` property in `state` has no `title` and `menu` properties, so you pass an empty array to `Menu` component. That's why you have an error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. You should change your state initialization in `constructor`.

```
class Nav extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            navigation: {//<-- change an empty array to object with a structure like a response from the server 
                menu: [],
                title: ''
            }
        }
    }

    //...

    render(){
        return (
            <Menu data={this.state.navigation} />
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, it is just that. Excuse me, but do you mind editing your answer and deleting the url and the server? Thank you very much for everything!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `componentWillMount` as it is deprecated and will soon disappear, the correct way is to use `componentDidMount` method along with a state variable and a test in your render.

```
this.state = {
    navigation: [],
    init: false
}
```

---

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('json_menuFIN.php')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
         this.setState({ navigation: data, init: true });
         console.log( data)
    })
}
```

Also, you cannot extract the `data` variable from your `navigation` variable in the state, `navigation` has been defined with your `data` response, so use it directly.

```
render() {
    const { navigation, init } = this.state;

    if(!init) return null

    return (
        <Menu data={navigation}/>
    )        
}
```

I assume that `navigation` is always an array, whatever you do with it.